# SQL - Database design issue on storing list of data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of records to be stored in database table, but I'm facing some difficulty in designing the database. The following would be the data to be stored:

[image]

The Class (Rows) and The Day (Column) will be continue to grow in future. My initial idea have 2 designs.

1. The table design for the database design will be exactly same with the current table. But the problem would be how if want to add Day13? It would be suffer in future in the column keep continue to grow.
2. Add 1 column as result:

[image]

It look better to solve the problem of Day column to be growing in future, but the problem is it will keep large amount of data records in database which make query become slower when more and more data insert.

Any idea or technique on how to optimize the database design? Thank you.

Comment: Your secound attempt is absolutely fine.

Comment: Your three column design is good and solves most of the problems with your original design.  Though you might want to store actual dates instead of/in addition to the day.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That is just a simple example I provided, I actual database would much more complex

Comment: @lbueker  But how is the problem of querying data, since data grow very fast, the query become slower and somehow when querying the data, it shows 'out of memory exception'

Comment: Based on the problem you actually showed us, you have solved your own problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ya, I think the second design would be much better, since data grow very fast, the query become slower and somehow when querying the data, it shows 'out of memory exception'

Comment: Store the class id and the date

Comment: Let's say you had 10 times as many classes as shown here. This would still only grow by 130 rows per day. In 100 years time, this would still be a small dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something simple like this.

One table for Classes (ClassID, ClassName)

One table for Day/Period/whatever you call it (DayID, DayName, DayInMonth etc..)

One table for Results(ResultId,DayId,ClassId, Result)

Answer (score 0):

So a Class can have a result and a date. Just make sure to have a unique primary key on your Class table and make the correct data types for your fields. 
What I think you need is a ClassId for primary key and then make a ClassName field (varchar) to store the class name. Don't write Day1 it should be a date format.